# How to Show Dialog while user do Tap on List Item Row

Tags: android, android-listview

whenever user do tap on list item row i am trying to show dialog, but getting nothing whenever i do click on list item row, why?

Here I just want to update value of total by accepting new qty from user in dialog via show that value in place of quantity in a List row ....

**CartActivity.java:**

```
public class CartActivity extends Activity {

    ListView mLstView1;
    CartAdapter mViewCartAdpt;

    final private static int DIALOG_QUANTITY = 1;
    EditText update_quantity ;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_cart);

            mLstView1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
            mViewCartAdpt = new CartAdapter(CartActivity.this);
            mLstView1.setAdapter(mViewCartAdpt);
            mLstView1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

             @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                     final int position, long id) 
             {       
                 showDialog(DIALOG_QUANTITY);
            }
        }); 
    } 

    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {

        AlertDialog dialogDetails = null;
            switch (id) {
            case DIALOG_QUANTITY:
                LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
                View dialogview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_layout, null);
                AlertDialog.Builder dialogbuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                dialogbuilder.setTitle("Image Information");
                dialogbuilder.setView(dialogview);
                dialogDetails = dialogbuilder.create();
                break;  
            }
            return dialogDetails;
    }

    protected void onPrepareDialog(int id, Dialog dialog) {
        switch (id) {
        case DIALOG_QUANTITY:
        final AlertDialog alertDialog = (AlertDialog) dialog;
            Button updateQuantityButton = (Button) alertDialog
                    .findViewById(R.id.btn_login);
            Button cancelbutton = (Button) alertDialog
                    .findViewById(R.id.btn_cancel);
            update_quantity = (EditText) alertDialog
                    .findViewById(R.id.edit_new_qty);                   

            updateQuantityButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {   

                }

            });

            cancelbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override                   
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        alertDialog.dismiss();
                    }
            });
            break;
        }
    }

    // Called when the activity begins interacting with the user
    @Override
    protected void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        mViewCartAdpt.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }   
}
```

**CartAdapter.java:**

```
public class CartAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    public static final String LOG_TAG = "CartAdapter";

    public static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
    public static final String KEY_COST = "cost";
    public static final String KEY_QTY = "qty";
    public static final String KEY_TOTAL = "total";

    Activity activity;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    ImageButton mImgBtnDelete;  
    ListView listView;

    private double itemamount = 0;
    private int itemquantity = 0;



    public CartAdapter(Activity a) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        activity = a;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return Constants.sItem_Detail.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View vi = convertView;
        if (convertView == null)
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listrow_cart, null);  // listrow_cart

         vi.setClickable(true);
         vi.setFocusable(true);          

         vi.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

             @Override
             public void onClick(View v) 
             {                       

             }       
         }); 

            final TextView title = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.title);
            final TextView qty = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.qty);
            final TextView cost = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.cost);
            final TextView total = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.total);


            HashMap<String, String> item = new HashMap<String, String>();
            item = Constants.sItem_Detail.get(position);

            // Setting all values in listview

            title.setText(item.get(com.example.sample.ItemsActivity.KEY_TITLE));
            cost.setText(item.get(com.example.sample.ItemsActivity.KEY_COST));
            qty.setText("1");

            itemquantity = Integer.parseInt(qty.getText().toString());
            itemamount = Double.parseDouble(cost.getText().toString());
            total.setText(new DecimalFormat("##.#").format(itemamount*itemquantity));

        return vi;

    }   
}
```

Comment: what's wrong in this question? why it has down voted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take your Dialog inside your activity, where you have to do code for listiview click, inside click show your dialog,

```
 list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
          public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> myAdapter, View myView, int myItemInt, long mylng) {
         //show dialog.      

          }                 
    });
```

I can see, your dialog having two buttons and one editbox, and whatever values is to be input in editbox, you updating your list value with editbox value.

Grab editbox value and update your list array, which you are setting on adapter to fill your listview.

```
updateQuantityButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {   
                  // here  you have to fetch editbox value and update your arraylist and then notify your adapter.
                }

            });
```

Comment: i agree with you and i realized that as well, but still a doubt in my mind how can i do update my qty in list item row by accepting quantity via DialogBox because all the values are given in ADAPTER CLASS

Comment: pass your `HashMap<String, String> item = new HashMap<String, String>();` from activity to adapter class and update your `HashMap<String, String> item = new HashMap<String, String>();` inside your dialog with new vlaue and then last notify your adapter.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this way when click on item of the list view then open the dialog box  and whatever changes or update in list then use `setNotifyDataChanged()` before set the adapter on list view

```
 lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
          public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> myAdapter, View myView, int myItemInt, long mylng) {
          yourActivty.this.showDialog(DIALOG_QUANTITY);          

          }                 
    });
```

Comment: yes you use this thing in activity class rather than  in getview

Comment: please check my updated code, but still not getting Dialogbox while do tap on list item row

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is because `onCreateDialog()` and `onPrepareDialog()` should be overriden in an activity, not in the adapter.
Since you declared `activity` to be of type `Activity`, calling `activity.showDialog()` won't have any effect.

What you have to do, is to move those methods in the activity you want the dialogs to be displayed, then pass to the `CardAdapter` and instance of your activity and use it in the adapter.

```
new CardAdapter(MyActivity.this);
//...
public class CardAdapter .... {
   public MyActivity activity;
   //.......

   activity.showDialog
}
```

Though, I would suggest to use `DialogFragment` instead.